# asp:PlaceHolder y JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net, radiobutton

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual estoy usando **asp:PlaceHolder** y esta etiqueta contiene un **radiobuttonlist**, pero este radiobuttonlist no lo estoy manejando desde el HTML sino que lo manejo desde el C#.

La pregunta que tengo es: ¿Se puede acceder al raddiobuttonlist por medio de JavaScript?, si es así ¿Como lo puedo hacer?

Este es mi código:

HTML

`<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phdejemplo"></asp:PlaceHolder>`

C#

```
private void RadioButtonEjemplo(Pregunta pregunta, bool esVisible)
    {
        var rblRespuestasEjemplo = new RadioButtonList();
        rblRespuestasEjemplo.ID = "rblPregunta" + pregunta.PreguntaId;
        rblRespuestasEjemplo.Visible = esVisible;
        rblRespuestasEjemplo.RepeatDirection = pregunta.ModoVisualizacion ? RepeatDirection.Vertical : RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
        rblRespuestasEjemplo.AutoPostBack = true;
        rblRespuestasEjemplo.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) => rblRespuestasEjemplo_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e, pregunta.PreguntaId);

        phdejemplo.Controls.Add(rblRespuestasEjemplo);

    }

private void rblRespuestasEjemplo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, int preguntaId)
    {
        RadioButtonList radio = (RadioButtonList)sender;
        var respuestaSeleccionadaId = Convert.ToInt32(radio.SelectedValue);
    }
```

Lo que quiero hacer con el JavaScript es saber si un radiobutton fue seleccionado.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal algo parecido a esto en tu botón u otro objeto:

`OnChange="javascript:CogeRegistro();return false;"`   Si hay algún cambio

`OnClick ="javascript:MiRutina();"`   Si pulsan

Es una forma de llamar a tu función de javaScript desde el propio botón.

Yo lo utilizo así, pero te sugiero que poco a poco cambies a JQuery

Puedes escribirlo desde el código trasero en C#, es decir, obligas al código trasero a que escriba lo que quieras dentro de la página en el PlaceHolder o donde quieras. 
El código sería algo como:

`PlaceMenu.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<Escribe aquí... el código HTML o el botón, o...>"));`

Luego además de escribirlo, accedes a él desde javascript, c# o lo que necesites.